# Eclipse RCP - How to run my application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have only just started RCP development with Eclipse I am looking at some tutorials but my question is how to run the actual applicaiton...in the run options I only get run as a RAP application or run as an eclipse application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run as Eclipse Application is the correct way to run an RCP.

Eclipse should find the correct product and/or application id from the RCP plugin.xml. You can check this by looking at the 'Run Configuration' that gets created when you run the RCP.

Answer (score 0):

Running as an eclipse application is a recommended way to run your rcp application.. you can run that app by adding product configuration to it(Right Click on the project folder and select new->Product Configuration)